# Different DNS server answer me different things

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server

I am having problem with email going **to** "jslawglobe.com".
From certain email it always works. From others, it is a matter of luck.

After investigating the problem with one of those **sender emails** from which it does not work:

```
nslookup -type=MX jslawglobe.com
```

Returned:

```
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8
*** dns.google can't find jslawglobe.com: Server failed
```

What is most weird is that on my own laptop:

```
nslookup -type=MX jslawglobe.com
```

Returned:

```
Server:  G3100.myfiosgateway.com
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
jslawglobe.com  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt4.aspmx.l.google.com
jslawglobe.com  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt3.aspmx.l.google.com
jslawglobe.com  MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
jslawglobe.com  MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
jslawglobe.com  MX preference = 1, mail exchanger = aspmx.l.google.com
```

But Command:

```
nslookup -type=MX jslawglobe.com  8.8.8.8
```

Returned:

```
Server:  dns.google  
Address:  8.8.8.8
 
*** dns.google can't find jslawglobe.com: Server failed
```

Why 2 DNS server give me such different answer? This is not temporary, it has been like this for a week at least but most likely 4 months.

Comment: https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=jslawglobe.com&type=MX&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=all&nameservers=

Comment: https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=jslawglobe.com&type=NS&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=all&nameservers=a.gtld-servers.net.

Comment: My guess it is some networking issues in cloudflare network

Comment: https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=jslawglobe.com&type=NS&trace=on&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=all&nameservers=a.gtld-servers.net.

Comment: https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=jslawglobe.com&type=MX&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=self&nameservers=quinton.ns.cloudflare.com.%0D%0Akehlani.ns.cloudflare.com.

Comment: Thanks for all these great diagnostics. Any conclusions from them? I thought DNS servers are supposed to sync with each other, no? How do I fix this problem?

Comment: As you may see problem is not on your side. Use nameserver that work for you. Contact with administration of jslawglobe.com domain

Comment: I am the admin of jslawglobe.com domain :-P

Comment: You have signed delegation https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=jslawglobe.com.&type=DS&showcommand=on&stats=on&dnssec=on&useresolver=8.8.8.8&ns=nic&nameservers=quinton.ns.cloudflare.com.%0D%0Akehlani.ns.cloudflare.com but no dnskeys https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=jslawglobe.com.&type=DNSKEY&showcommand=on&stats=on&dnssec=on&useresolver=1.1.1.1&ns=auth&nameservers=quinton.ns.cloudflare.com.%0D%0Akehlani.ns.cloudflare.com

Comment: https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=jslawglobe.com.&type=DNSKEY&showcommand=on&stats=on&dnssec=on&ns=resolver&useresolver=1.1.1.1&nameservers=quinton.ns.cloudflare.com.%0D%0Akehlani.ns.cloudflare.com https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/jslawglobe.com

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-and-validate-dnssec-using-dig-command-line/ https://metebalci.com/blog/a-minimum-complete-tutorial-of-dnssec/

Comment: https://dnsviz.net/d/jslawglobe.com/dnssec/

Comment: You need configure dnssec or disable signed delegation on your dns registrar

Comment: This is right! Thanks. And my registrar does not allow that, so I am changing registrar. If you post it as an answer, I can select it as right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I encouter this sort of fault it's that the DNS of the destination has broken DNSSEC records.

(here's a log line written by an instance of bind)

```
Sep 19 20:17:07 ZZZZZ named[14371]: validating jslawglobe.com/MX: got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure
```

This time it's no different.

jslawglobe.com needs to contact the person who maintains their DNS records and have them fix this problem.

Comment: This is exactly the case. There is DS record at the delegation point (.com nameservers) but no DNSKEY record(s) at authoritative nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

After deep digging figure out next (see comments under original question).

Some DNS resolvers returns `status: SERVFAIL`.

`jslawglobe.com` has a signed delegation from the `com` zone, but does not have a `DNSKEY` record on its NS, so the DNSSEC configuration is broken. So some DNS resolvers ignore broken DNSSEC and respond, others don't ignore and don't respond.

You need to configure dnssec or disable signed delegation on your dns registrar.

```
dig NS +additional jslawglobe.com. @8.8.4.4
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8 <<>> NS +additional jslawglobe.com. @8.8.4.4
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 20791
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jslawglobe.com.            IN  NS

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 20 12:32:49 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32


jslawglobe.com@94.140.14.14 (AdGuard (CY)):  Copy results to clipboard
dig NS +additional jslawglobe.com. @94.140.14.14
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8 <<>> NS +additional jslawglobe.com. @94.140.14.14
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 27191
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jslawglobe.com.            IN  NS

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 94.140.14.14#53(94.140.14.14)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 20 12:32:49 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
jslawglobe.com@165.87.13.129 (AT&T (US)):  Copy results to clipboard
dig NS +additional jslawglobe.com. @165.87.13.129
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8 <<>> NS +additional jslawglobe.com. @165.87.13.129
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44457
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 12

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jslawglobe.com.            IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
jslawglobe.com.     86400   IN  NS  kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com.
jslawglobe.com.     86400   IN  NS  quinton.ns.cloudflare.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com. 78728 IN A   108.162.194.223
kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com. 78728 IN A   162.159.38.223
kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com. 78728 IN A   172.64.34.223
quinton.ns.cloudflare.com. 164999 IN    A   172.64.35.249
quinton.ns.cloudflare.com. 164999 IN    A   108.162.195.249
quinton.ns.cloudflare.com. 164999 IN    A   162.159.44.249
kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com. 78728 IN AAAA    2a06:98c1:50::ac40:22df
kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com. 78728 IN AAAA    2606:4700:50::a29f:26df
kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com. 78728 IN AAAA    2803:f800:50::6ca2:c2df
quinton.ns.cloudflare.com. 164999 IN    AAAA    2606:4700:58::a29f:2cf9
quinton.ns.cloudflare.com. 164999 IN    AAAA    2803:f800:50::6ca2:c3f9
quinton.ns.cloudflare.com. 164999 IN    AAAA    2a06:98c1:50::ac40:23f9

;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: 165.87.13.129#53(165.87.13.129)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 20 12:32:49 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 354
```

com. zone

```
dig DS +additional +multiline +dnssec jslawglobe.com. @e.gtld-servers.net.
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8 <<>> DS +additional +multiline +dnssec jslawglobe.com. @e.gtld-servers.net.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5877
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 14, ADDITIONAL: 27
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jslawglobe.com.        IN DS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
jslawglobe.com.     86400 IN DS 49211 8 2 (
                EEE39935BA7E61FFAD077F04F6877495B659B1295712
                B2A67BD03F470EFE0F2F )
jslawglobe.com.     86400 IN RRSIG DS 8 2 86400 20220927052146 (
                20220920041146 32298 com.
                qGgZ3u9IGoNHnN3z6o6yuW2LHh7iyjvEgICFWUI98ZGU
                Si+/drWBe0nmZOiQAGQRtUAE71lbbCloZ1R6y585PTJW
                Z+1aC5k40/bNVP/gi9nWmrSWSFAzupXmbZ5yEgSxFT5z
                1b5Pvrhg9DnE2xteTaaQJMPJT6Wx+YOQm7qawji2Q54u
                xc2wto57Vpv84wmq1NWjM/Ed5g9FmVa5NB9mDg== )
```

jslawglobe.com. name servers

```
dig DNSKEY +additional +multiline +dnssec jslawglobe.com. @kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com.
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8 <<>> DNSKEY +additional +multiline +dnssec jslawglobe.com. @kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9460
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jslawglobe.com.        IN DNSKEY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
jslawglobe.com.     3600 IN SOA kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. (
                2286759303 ; serial
                10000      ; refresh (2 hours 46 minutes 40 seconds)
                2400       ; retry (40 minutes)
                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
                )

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 172.64.34.223#53(172.64.34.223)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 20 12:27:16 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
jslawglobe.com.@quinton.ns.cloudflare.com.:  Copy results to clipboard
dig DNSKEY +additional +multiline +dnssec jslawglobe.com. @quinton.ns.cloudflare.com.
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.el6_10.8 <<>> DNSKEY +additional +multiline +dnssec jslawglobe.com. @quinton.ns.cloudflare.com.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31849
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jslawglobe.com.        IN DNSKEY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
jslawglobe.com.     3600 IN SOA kehlani.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. (
                2286759303 ; serial
                10000      ; refresh (2 hours 46 minutes 40 seconds)
                2400       ; retry (40 minutes)
                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                3600       ; minimum (1 hour)
                )

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 172.64.35.249#53(172.64.35.249)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 20 12:27:16 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
```

[image]

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-test-and-validate-dnssec-using-dig-command-line/

https://metebalci.com/blog/a-minimum-complete-tutorial-of-dnssec/

https://dnsviz.net/d/jslawglobe.com/dnssec/

https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/jslawglobe.com

Answer (score -4):

Google DNS might check that the TXT record has an entry called SPF (within TXT).

Look for SPF records on Google search. There are plenty of article and good tutorial.

Comment: the reason for all the downvotes is probably because SPF does not influence the working of DNS at all.

Comment: That is why there is a keyword in the sentence ''might'' as ''may be'' ;-)